# How to test the code using NUnit unit tests in F#

Tags: dll, f#, nunit

I have a .dll file and I want to test the code with NUnit testing.

Could you give me any example about how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? Do you not know how to use NUnit at all, or is this specifically about using it with F#? Testing F# should be very similar to testing C#.

Comment: The structure may be the same, but actually I've never made such a test in C# before. If you would give me an example from C#, it might be useful. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to test F# code. Take a look at the section "Community Projects: Testing Tools" on F# foundation page: http://fsharp.org/community/projects/

Specifically for using NUnit FSharpTest template is very useful https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a52388eb-e1d3-4900-a25a-d18c8d23a1f3